# What is the best way of organizing Rails functional and unit test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have been organizing my test cases by a hierarchy of controller/action/scenario or model/method/scenario. It looks natural and clear. But I found I had to setup test data repetitively for different actions and methods for the same scenario. Although I can reduce code redundancy by code reuse. But I think it is still time-wasting especially for the machine to setup these test data again and again. Is there anybody organizing these test cases by scenarios? What is the best way of organizing test cases?

Comment: Are you using test::unit or rspec?

Comment: I have been using rspec. Is this dependent on the test framework? I thought it was a general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** this question is about repeating yourself when generating test data you should probably look at the following gems that helps you generate test data:

- factory_girl
- [Fabrication](http://fabricationgem.org)

**If** this question is about delay when running test, you should probably look at [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork).

**And if** this question is about organizing test, one approach that I guess is quite common is to separate tests into unit tests and functional tests.

Tests all the methods, one by one, in unit tests. And tests all the scenarios in functional tests.

spec/unit/user_spec.rb

```
describe "#generate_password_salt" do
  user = User.new(password: 'foobar')
  user.generate_password_salt.should == '1231asdas'
end
```

spec/functional/user_spec.rb

```
describe "when creating new user" do
  it "should generate password salt" do
     ...
  end      
end
```

Comment: Actually my question is whether there are general patterns to follow in organizing these unit tests/functional tests. It looks natural to organize them by methods(actions) and then by scenarios. But I found I always ended up having to set up similar test data sets again and again. Although tools like Factory Girl help to reduce the effort to set up test data, I am still wondering if I can organize these tests  so they can share the same set of test data. But now I think this probably really depends on the application we are working on.